# CSS triangle side with round on left?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create this as below and couldn't finish it.

I can only manage to create a rounded corners on left but not slanted right.

[image: align top]
<sub>(source: [kerrydeaf.com](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/arrow.png))</sub>

```
#talkbubble
 {
width: 100px;
height: 35px;
background: #FFCC05;
position: relative;
-moz-border-radius:8px 0 0 8px;
-webkit-border-radius:8px 0 0 8px;
border-radius:8px 0 0 8px;
margin-right:50px;
 }
```

Or here is
http://jsfiddle.net/alma/USezL/23/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think this is what u are looking for http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

http://jsfiddle.net/zQKhb/

```
#talkbubble 
{ 
    width: 100px;
    height: 36px;
    background: #FFCC05;
    position: relative;
    -moz-border-radius:8px 0 0 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius:8px 0 0 8px;
    border-radius:8px 0 0 8px;
    margin-right:50px;

} 

#talkbubble:before
{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -36px;
    top:0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 18px solid transparent;

    border-color: transparent transparent #FFCC05 #FFCC05;
}
​
```

Comment: Aww, did you just beat me to it with almost exactly the same solution?

Comment: Thank you Rene. Its perfect too.

Comment: sorry mate :) ... yours did have a more detailed explaination on what OP was missing.

Answer (score 2):

You were missing some crucial points in your triangle on the right. First of all, by default a :before element is `display: inline`, so to create the effect you were seeking you needed `display: block` instead.

Second, the `right: 120px` was moving it 120 pixels away from the right side of its original position. That is, it was being pushed to the left, out of view. Instead, you needed a negative right position (move *to* the right) of 100% (the width of the speech bubble). That way, it'd end up to the right of it.

Third, not sure what shape you were going for but it was almost everything but a triangle ;).

I went for this instead:

```
#talkbubble:before
{
    content:" ";
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    right: -100%;

    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 0 solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;    
    border-bottom: 35px solid #FFCC05;
}
```

​The first part is for the positioning, the second part is creating the actual triangle (see http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/).

In the jsfiddle I made the triangle blue so you can see exactly where it is. Change the border-right width to make the angle bigger. http://jsfiddle.net/USezL/31/

Comment: Thank you Stephen. Its perfect. Yes, I've missed some crucial points that is why I asked on stackoverflow.

Comment: No problem, just wanted to point out what I did differently so you could learn from it.

Comment: Oh, and a tip for debugging: set `outline: red solid thin` to the before element to see where it's going. Then after positioning it right, remove that again :)